# Chromatic polynomial of simple graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, algebraic-graph-theory

Suppose I know the chromatic polynomial $P(G, \lambda)$  of the graph $G$. Can we  express   the chromatic polynomial of  the graph $G'$ in terms of $P(G, \lambda)$  and $\lambda$?

I have tried to apply the deletion-contraction but without any success.
[image]

Comment: What is the relation of $G'$ to $G$? in general.

Comment: All relations are on the pictures, I have no add more information.

Comment: They have 10 vertices

Comment: Since you can express $P(G',\lambda)$ in terms of $\lambda$, a fortiori you can express $P(G',\lambda)$ in terms of $P(G,\lambda)$ and $\lambda$. But that's not what you meant. Deletion-contraction is all I can think of, and it brings in a third, nontrivial graph, so I think the answer to the question, in the sense you had in mind, is, no.